# Why are some questions tagged [fun]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [6 questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun) on the main site currently tagged `fun`.
What is the sense in this? Aren't all games supposed to be fun? A search for the word fun in text turns up [3 pages](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=fun) of results.

Is there any reason those 6 questions are tagged `fun`? The reason I ask is because those questions are disproportionately about Dwarf Fortress, and maybe some elements of that game do justify the tag.
Comments on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5169/) and [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4300) suggest this may be the case. If so, perhaps such a generic-sounding tag should be renamed to `dwarf-fortress-fun`?

Comment: *Are* all games supposed to be fun? Is being required to spend at least 8 hours playing the original Half-Life in order to get a passing mark in a college class "fun"? ... ...well, yes, it was fun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an in-joke. Anything negative that happens in Dwarf Fortress (like flooding your fort after cutting through the wrong stone or wounding a dwarf) is referred to as fun, as it is the most entertaining part of the game.

Fun is actually a redirect to Losing on their wiki, and it does apply to DF as such. It might be a good idea to rename it to something like `[df-fun]` or `[dwarf-fortress-fun]`

Comment: For now, I've used the mass-retag to move all of these into [dwarf-fortress-fun], so that we won't end up spreading [fun] to the rest of the world. We can discuss condensing the name or similar aspects, but I wanted to get that over with first.

Comment: @Grace we definitely don't want to spread fun to the rest of the world.  Imagine what they'd do with it!

Comment: If "fun" refers to flooding one's home from an underground river, I imagine the rest of the world will be grateful. ;)

Answer (score -1):

They're using the tag in an ironic sense? Because it feels like work? I agree. I think it should be changed somehow. But I'm not sure what should be done to change it.

Comment: Dwarf Fortress certainly doesn't feel like work, Dwarf Fortress is [Fun](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Losing)