# Why do we have tags like diablo-3-demon-hunter?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, search, sub-tags

The tags for questions concerning Diablo 3 characters look very redundant like this:

- [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3)
- [diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter)

For Starcraft there is no [starcraft-1-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-1-terran) and [starcraft-2-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-terran). It is just [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran).

I understand that the term demon hunter is used in multiple games and selecting just demon hunter might confuse some people, because the questions might be for Warcraft 3 and WoW, but I assume everybody understands how to query a search bar. Plus it is the same for tags like micro.

I suggest to  change [diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter) etc. to [demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demon-hunter) and perhaps explain how the search bar works, e.g. searching for "[diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) [demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demon-hunter)" would yield the same results as "[diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter)". Especially after someone selects a specific tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The primary reason for tags is not for searching. You can just search for "diablo 3 demon hunter", no square brackets, and it will work just fine. Tags are primarily used for filtering - e.g. if someone is interested in all Demon Hunter questions she can "star" the tag (follow it), and then questions about it will be tinted differently and it will be included in the ["my tags" tab of the unanswered questions page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags).

Likewise, if someone wants to filter *away* all questions about Witch Doctor, because he doesn't play that class, he can mark that tag is ignored.

So, why [diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter) and not just [demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demon-hunter)? Because "Demon Hunter" is not unique enough to Diablo III. And even if it is, [monk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monk) and [wizard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wizard) definitely aren't. And now this may collide with, say, the hypoethetical [wow-wizard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wow-wizard).

[zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg), [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) and [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss) are pretty unique, so we don't need the prefix there. If Diablo III's class names were far more unique, such as "Zacharum Warrior", I don't think we'd need the prefix there, either.

Or at least, this is my opinion :) I've also wrote about in in [another meta-question which discussed the validity of these tags in the first place](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4547/122).

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was going to say, but you beat me to the punch :)

Comment: But would it not be even cooler if you could specify tag sets for this. E.g. I am interested in [diablo-3][monk] but not in [diablo-3][wizard] etc. This would also solve this. But I see your point and this is just another suggestion.

Comment: @ayckoster well our platform doesn't support that. You are welcome to open a feature-request about it here in meta, though! The StackExchange team is usually opposed to adding features only to one site of the Stack Exchange site family, though, so I recommend that you try to make your case as solid as possible if you want to ask for such a feature, or otherwise show how it is applicable to all the network's sites.

Comment: @ayckoster The problem is that "tag sets" aren't supported by the tagging system. We have made requests for changes, but they have been denied (apparently the tag system is *Really* hard to change, due to the way the site is designed). Therefore we need to do our best with the system we are given.

Comment: @ayckoster: I also get the feeling that this would require hierarchal tagging, which has been explicitly denied in the past (see the Sci-Fi and and Fantasy [meta post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/528/1068) where I discussed a similar issue, and [Joel's initial reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89931/150515) for not doing something like this in the first place).