# Burn the Diablo 3 class tags!

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just browsing the tags and I noticed that the class tags for Diablo 3 still exist.

I don't feel like they are necessary. They are used sparingly nowadays. Even in general compared to the total amount of  [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) questions. Also we don't have class/role specific tags anymore on this site so I don't see why this should be any different in Diablo. They are also always used together with either the [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) or [diablo-3-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-console) tags.

The main problem I see with the class tags are their inconsistency. There are a ton of [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) class-related questions without the appropriate class tag but nobody bothers to retag them (and right now they are probably too many to do so manually).

So here's a suggestion to burninate all the Diablo-3 class tags since they are outdated and don't fit the tag scheme of this page anymore:

- [diablo-3-barbarian](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-barbarian)
- [diablo-3-crusader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-crusader)
- [diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter)
- [diablo-3-monk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-monk)
- [diablo-3-necromancer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-necromancer)
- [diablo-3-witch-doctor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-witch-doctor)
- [diablo-3-wizard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-wizard)

Comment: Context: [Where we initially decided to allow them](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/should-we-allow-tags-for-a-specific-class-in-rpg-games) and [some statistics on how they did after a little while](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4767/class-tags-and-diablo-3).

Comment: Feature request is a bad tag for this.

Comment: *"We don't have class/role specific tags anymore on this site"* - When was this decided? [TF2 Begs to differ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2-*), as far as I can tell the decision for subtags is made on a game-by-game basis, either done organically or through an organised effort. Even if "used sparingly nowadays", if the D3 subtags provide a useful grouping of content why would we expend the effort to remove them? The effort to gain ratio seems pretty low...

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the main problem. They weren't used correctly and there are too many questions to retroactively fix. No new questions are going to use these tags and I don't see the point in having them. Very few users come here to look up specific class-based questions anyway and even if they did, because they weren't used correctly, they are useless.